# Can't boot from any os from hard disk after insalling Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm new at Ubuntu, I've tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 7 which is current os in my laptop. For this;

1. I installed Ubuntu iso file and burned to a usb stick with rufus
2. When I boot from USB there is an option to install Ubuntu, I selected it
3. During installation I clicked force uefi mode and from there selected install alongside windows 7 option.
4. Everything was same with tutorials I've followed

But, When I unpluged usb and restarted pc, I got an error something like "no os in your hard disk, please install os to your hard disk".

Then, I run ubuntu from usb again, and run boot repair using following code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

First I followed recommended repair but it didn't work. Second time, I chose default boot option as Windows from Advanced options menu but it didn't work. How can I solve this?

### UPDATE

after enabling legacy mode from BIOS I can access ubuntu installed on hard disk, but I'm still searching my Windows 7 :D

Many thanks in advance

Comment: win7 is efi mode? you installed ubuntu in legacy mode.

Comment: The description makes it sound like Ubuntu was installed in *EFI* mode to a system that already held a *BIOS-mode* Windows installation, not the other way around. The URL provided by Boot Repair would likely clarify matters. (This may be moot, though; if Boot Repair has fixed things, then that's great, although it leaves the question of precisely what happened to derail the installation.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is my problem. As @ravery mentioned I've installed ubuntu in legacy mode, so I enabled it from BIOS and grub brought me ubuntu only then I run boot repair in advanced mode selecting default os windows again. At it worked !!!